How to disable buffer_output when using Symfony's build in server?
My eventual goal is to create an SSE stream, but for now I just created a simple php file in the public folder of my Symfony project. The code in it has nothing to do with Symfony:
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

echo "data: 1\n\n"; flush(); sleep(1);
echo "data: 2\n\n"; flush(); sleep(1);
echo "data: 3\n\n"; flush(); sleep(1);
echo "data: 4\n\n"; flush(); sleep(1);

When I open my command line and run php public/sse.php I get 1 line every second, just as I expect/trying to achieve.
However, when I run Symfony's webserver (symfony server:start -d) and then try to curl https://127.0.0.1:8000/sse.php nothing happens for 4 seconds and then I see all the output at once. Seems like Symfony server is still buffering the output, but I don't know why.
I tried:

php -i | grep output_buffering returns "output_buffering => 0 => 0"
ran the curl command with --insecure, in case it got stuck on SSL issues
to add ob_end_flush the first echo line

None of it worked. Any ideas?
Edit after a day:

When running the symfony server and I try curl --no-buffer -H 'Accept: text/event-stream' https://127.0.0.1:8000/sse.php it outputs everything all at once. (I see an incoming request in the logs)
When I try it directly with php no incoming request and output is not buffered.
When running the php server both php and curl work.
Further suggesting it's a setting/issue with the symfony server
When I change the lines echo "data: 1\n\n"; flush(); sleep(1); to for instance echo str_repeat('1', 4096) . "\n\n"; flush(); sleep(1); it does get buffered.
I'm lost lol


not an answer, but have you seen https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/main/server-sent-events/sse.php

Have you seen the Mercure component for Symfony ? Through this you can publish messages on the hub and consume them through SSE
